# CSS transform rotate works strangely on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, transform

When I check on Firefox, it works great. But when using Chrome 37, the transform rotate doesn't work well.

Can anyone can help me explain what is happening here?

Here my code:

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/thehung1724/full/BxKvD/

**HTML**

```
<div id="team">
  <div class="content-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <div class="team-box">
            <img src="http://content.screencast.com/users/HungSzczesny/folders/Default/media/fd5d4869-0a99-4157-9494-41ccea7ca71d/team-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="ImageOverlay"></div>
          </div>    <!-- end team-box -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <div class="team-box">
            <img src="http://content.screencast.com/users/HungSzczesny/folders/Default/media/0e07023a-77e8-4187-aec3-64e5498d2153/team-2.jpg" alt="">

            <div class="ImageOverlay"></div>
          </div>    <!-- end team-box -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <div class="team-box">
            <img src="http://content.screencast.com/users/HungSzczesny/folders/Default/media/389660c7-1e6b-45f5-840c-100822f704f4/team-3.jpg" alt="">

            <div class="ImageOverlay"></div>
          </div>    <!-- end team-box -->
        </div>
      </div>    <!-- end row -->
    </div>  <!-- end container -->
  </div>    <!-- end content-section -->
</div>  <!-- end team -->
```

**CSS (LESS)**

```
.team-box{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 254px;
    height: 254px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    .border-radius(50%);

    .ImageOverlay{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        height: 254px;
        width: 254px;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(0);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(0);
        -o-transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(0);
        transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(0);
        .transition(~"all 0.3s ease 0s");
    }

    &:hover{
        .ImageOverlay{
            .transform(rotate(0) scale(1));
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've changed your demo now, but as pointed out elsewhere, you need this:

```
.team-box {
   z-index:1;
}
```